# LinkedIn API Video Upload process

Tags: video, linkedin-api

Does anyone have a sample of an http request flow to upload videos to LinkedIn via API.  The discussions here on SO are about 4 years old and reference deprecated LI API methods.  What is the proper current way to upload via API?

When I use the documented method I get a 200 response, but the video is not actually uploaded

(ref:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2023-08&tabs=http)

Comment: did you get this resolved? I'm having the same problem. I can use the curl command to successfully upload the video but cannot use the HTTP requests to do the same.

Comment: Jude - I did, well at least within Tray.io.  I used the curl request within one of their connectors...